# Compute Lipschitz constant of piecewise linear in $\Bbb R^d$.

Tags: lipschitz-functions

Suppose we define the piecewise linear functions in $[a, b]^d$ to be all functions that can be written in the form $f(x) = W_ix +  b_i, $ if $ x\in A_i$ where $ \{A_i|i=1, ..., n\}$ is a finite partition of $[a, b]^d$, $W_i\in \mathbb{R}^d$ and $b_i\in \mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$.
Are these functions Lipschitz functions?
If yes, can we detect their constants?
Thanks in regard.

Comment: Any thoughts on this problem? Did you try d=1 case?

Comment: Yes for d=1 everything is simple. I am having some trouble with d>1.